# Are questions about nonlinear narrative design on topic?

Tags: support

Quite simply, are questions discussing nonlinear storytelling techniques (web, bubble, heap), on-topic in this section of the SE-verse?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what all of those are, but if they are techniques for planning, writing, or refining a written work, then questions about them (and how to use them) are on-topic.